Density with exponential factor Inequality
I would like to prove the following conjecture: Let $a>0$, let $f(x)$, $x\ge0$, be a density function, and define the density,
$$
p(x;a) = \frac{e^{-ax}f(x)}{\int_0^{\infty}e^{-at}f(t)\hspace{1pt}dt},\;x\ge0
$$
where $f(x)$ does not depend on $a$. Let $X \sim p(x;a)$. Then,
$$
E(X) \ge a\hspace{1pt}\mathrm{Var}(X)
$$
This would imply a monotone likelihood inequality for a general class of densities related to the correlation coefficient.

No. E.g., let $a=1$ and, for a real $b>1$,
$$f(x)=C g(x)$$
for all real $x$, where
$$g(x):=e^x x^{-2}\,1(1<x<b)$$
and $C:=1/\int_1^b e^x x^{-2}\,dx$. Then $f$ is a p.d.f. and
$$p(x):=p(x;a)=cx^{-2}\,1(1<x<b),$$
where $c:=\frac b{b-1}$, so that
$$EX=c\ln b,\quad a\,Var\,X=Var\,X=c(b-1)-(c\ln b)^2>EX$$
for all large enough $b$, since $c\to1$ as $b\to\infty$.
Actually, here $b=9$ will do for the inequality $a\,Var\,X>EX$.
$\quad\Box$
